# FeedComment Trigger Does Not Fire

Tags: trigger

```apex
trigger UpdateCommStatus on FeedComment (before insert) {
    Id myProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile 
                       WHERE Name = 'CardinalCommerce Customer' limit 1].id;
    set<Id> feedparentIds = new set<Id>();
    for (FeedComment feedcs : trigger.new){
        feedparentIds.add(feedcs.ParentId);   
    }
    List<Case> Pros = new List<Case>();
    Pros = [SELECT CaseNumber, Id, Status, owner.type,OwnerId,owner.ProfileId FROM Case 
              WHERE Id =: feedparentIds ];
    if(pros.size()>0){
        for(Case cs : Pros){
            //if(cs.owner.type == 'User'){
                if(cs.owner.ProfileId == myProfileId && 
                           cs.Status == 'Awaiting Customer Feedback'){
                 cs.Status = 'Working';       
                }
            //}
        }
        update pros;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `ParentId` is for a `FeedItem`, not a `Case`.

Comment: Did you make sure it is active?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your trigger is active before assuming anything is wrong with the code itself. You can check for the `Status` to be `Active` in the metadata, or you can look at it through the UI and make sure `Active` is checked.

---

It seems likely you just want to change your trigger to fire on `FeedItem`, whose `ParentId` can, indeed, be a `Case`. While there are other trigger best practices you could incorporate, such as moving your logic out of the trigger body, simply changing `FeedComment` to `FeedItem` should do the trick. You probably also want to add some sort of filter on the content of the `FeedItem` or `FeedComment`, but that is outside the scope of your question.

---

**Edit**

It looks like I was mistaken, and `ParentId` will be the same as what is on the `FeedItem`. Upon looking more closely, it's not immediately clear why no records are found, but you might have better luck with the parent `FeedItem` records.

```
Set<Id> feedItemIds = new Set<Id>();
for (FeedComment comment : trigger.new) feedItemIds.add(comment.FeedItemId);
List<Case> relatedRecords = [
    SELECT Owner.ProfileId FROM Case WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT ParentId FROM FeedItem WHERE Id IN :feedItemIds
    )
];
```